# Best Practice for Related Model Validation in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

I would like to be able to validate a create form with related models before I initiate a save. I am saving an organization which has a number of related models. Since I have a number of many-to-many relationships I have to create the primary model first then go through a laborious process of separately creating each related model from the input data. I call a 'createRelated' method within the Organization repository after the initial organization is created.

```
public function createRelated($input)
{
    $this->orgtypes()->attach(1, ['objectstate_id' => ORGANIZATION_STARTED]);
    $this->addresses()->create(array_only($input, ['street1', 'zip', 'city', 'state_code']));
    for ($i=0; $i < 2; $i++) 
    { 
        if($input['phone_numbers_'.$i.'_number'])
        {
            $this->phoneNumbers()->create(['phone_number_type_id' => $input['phone_numbers_'.$i.'_phone_number_type_id'], 'number' => $input['phone_numbers_'.$i.'_number']]);
        }
    }  
    $this->procedures()->attach($input['procedures']);     
    $input['objectstate_id'] = USER_STARTED;
    $input['password'] = $this->encryptPassword($input['password']);
    $this->users()->create(array_only($input, ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'objectstate_id']));
    $this->profileElements()->create(['type' => 'short_description', 'content' => $input['short_description']]);
}
```

Having to call out each input and sending it to its appropriate model does NOT seem right to me, but that is what I heard on IRC as the 'right' way. But now I come to validation and currently there is no validation on create for these models even though the input may violate the validation rules. I am surprised that there is no naming convention (that I have seen) that clearly identifies related model input so that it can all be validated and created without manual processing like the above.  Any ideas on how to validate related input data before I start the above save transaction?

My validator for Organization looks like:

```
<?php namespace Acme\Validators\Organizations;

use Acme\Validators\ValidatorAbstract;

class Validator extends ValidatorAbstract {

   /**
    * Validation rules
    */
   protected $rules = array(
       'organization_name' => 'required'
   );

   /**
    * Custom Validation Messages
    */
   protected $messages = array(
   );

}

<?php namespace Acme\Validators;

use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag as MessageBag;


/*
* This class defines abstract Validator methods
*/

abstract class ValidatorAbstract implements ValidatorInterface {
   protected $validator;

   protected $input;

   protected $errors;

   /**
    * @param array $input
    *
    */
   public function __construct($input = NULL, MessageBag $bag)
   {
       $this->input = $input ?: \Input::all();

       $this->validator = \Validator::make($this->input, $this->rules, $this->messages);
       $this->errors = $bag;
   }

   /**
    * Run validation on input.
    *
    * @return boolean
    */
   public function passes()
   {
       if($this->validator->passes())
       {
           return true;
       }
       $this->errors = $this->validator->messages();

       return false;
   }

   /**
    * Get all errors stored.
    *
    * @return MessageBag
    */
   public function getErrors()
   {
       return $this->errors;
   }

   /**
    * Add new error.
    *
    * @return MessageBag
    */
   public function addError($key, $message)
   {
      return $this->errors->add($key, $message);
   }

}
```

My Abstract Repository class where I bring in Ardent

```
<?php namespace Acme\Repositories;

// use Eloquent;
use LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent;

/*
* This class defines Eloquent methods
*/

abstract class EloquentRepositoryAbstract extends Ardent implements RepositoryInterface {

   protected $guarded = [];

   public $timestamps = false;
   public $autoHydrateEntityFromInput = true;    // Ardent hydrates on new entries' validation
   public $forceEntityHydrationFromInput = true; // Ardent hydrates whenever validation is called
…
```

My controller:

```
<?php

use \Acme\Repositories\Organizations\OrganizationRepositoryInterface;
use \Acme\Validators\Organizations\Validator;
use \Acme\Validators\Users\EditValidator as UsersValidator;

class OrganizationsController extends BaseController {

   /**
    * Organization Repository
    *
    * @var repository
    * @var validator
    * @var usersValidator
    */
   protected $repository;
   protected $validator;
   protected $usersValidator;

   public function __construct(OrganizationRepositoryInterface $repository, 
                               Validator $validator,
                               UsersValidator $usersValidator)
   {
       $this->repository = $repository;
       $this->validator = $validator;
       $this->users_validator = $usersValidator;
   }
```

[…] Vanilla eloquent style store method:

```
   public function store()
   {
       $input = Input::all();
       $opasses = $this->validator->passes();
       $ppasses = $this->repository->validateProcedure($input);
       $upasses = $this->users_validator->passes();
       if($opasses && $ppasses['status'] && $upasses)
       {
           $new_organization = $this->repository->create(['organization_name' => $input['organization_name']]);  
           if($input['logo_url'])
           {
               $new_organization->processImage($input, Request::root());             
           }
           if($new_organization->saveRelated($input, 'create'))
           {
               return Redirect::route('home')
                   ->with('message', 'Organization Created.');               
           }
           else
           {
               return Redirect::route('organizations.create')
                   ->withInput()
                   ->with('message', 'There were errors in the creation of this Organization');              
           }
       }
       return Redirect::route('organizations.create')
           ->withInput()
           ->withErrors(array_merge($this->validator->getErrors()->toArray(), $this->users_validator->getErrors()->toArray(), $ppasses))
           ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');

   }
```

This all seems overly complex and brittle.

Answer (score 0):

I think the toughest decision is where to put the validation rules before invoking the validation method.  Here is a link that will help: http://laravel.com/docs/validation#available-validation-rules.

Here's how I did mine, but I'm still deciding where to put the validation rules/error messages.

Laravel 4's built-in validation class has one method that makes validating real easy:

```
Validator::make($input, $rules=array(), $errors=array())
```

(third parameter is optional)

In your case, before you call your create methods (assuming that's used to save the elements) you can do this:

```
$rules = array(
    "first_name" : "required",
    "second_name" : "required",
     and so on...
);
```

The link I gave you will give you the possible rules.  Finally, you can also create your own custom error messages like this:

```
$messages = array(
    "required" => "This :attribute field is required"
    and so on...
);
```

The :attribute will fill in the field that failed validation automatically.

Then, to validate you just pass in those arrays and call the passes() method or the fails() method:

`Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages)->passes()` 
(returns true if passed, false if failed)
It would look cleaner in my opinion to do it this way:

```
$validation = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
if ($validation->passes()) {
      // save data
}
```

As a bonus, you can access the error messages from this array:

```
$errors = $validation->messages();
```

So, I hope that answers your question.  I think the  biggest question is where to put these validation rules as I don't think there's a convention yet.  Please share your insights and opinion if you have any.  Thanks.

Comment: Well I currently have what I consider a poor solution. I am using the repository pattern and validations as a service.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a completely different topic from your original post since now you're asking about application architecture stuff rather than on how to validate input.